# Wordpress site in conteiner does't redirect to subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, lxc

For one of my client that has his website in wordpress I need to add some extra features to his custom them. Because I’m working on Ubuntu I decided to make a copy of this website and install it on my container to have backup on which I can work and here some problems appear. First I couldn’t enter the website because it redirected me to company domain. To change that I modified wp-options

```
 option_name: ‘siteurl’ option_value: ‘http://companydomain.com’
 option_name: ‘home’ option_value: ‘http://companydomain.com’
```

in wordpress database. Now everything works perfect except one think when I press on link that is linked to subdirectory in wordpress site I get page ‘Not Found’. Maybe anyone know what am I missing and is needed to be changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the rewrite rules of the site and that should get things working for you again. You can either call the [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) function, or more easily login to the dashboard and go to [**Settings > Permalinks**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen) and click the save button and that will automatically flush them for you.

Comment: Sorry still nothing I clicked save in Settings > Permalinks and I removed row from SELECT option_value FROM  `wp_options` WHERE  `option_name` =  'rewrite_rules'; -> and nothing change still page not found

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in the WordPress root directory? It may potentially be missing and unable to flush the rules.

Comment: yes I have # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: and mod_rewrite is enable as well